# Problem in Selenium with python (instagram crawler)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I just wrote this instagram crawler ,it's a little project for college. I will show you the code and upload a picture to show you what my problem is.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class App:
    def __init__(self,username="Enter your username here",password="Enter your password here",target_username="shriar.ha"):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.target_username = target_username
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Shahriar/Desktop/Selenium and BS projects/chromedriver.exe") #This is the path to webdriver in my PC ,you should change it and give the path of where your webdriver is located.
        self.main_url = "https://www.instagram.com"
        self.driver.get(self.main_url)
        sleep(5)
        self.log_in()
        self.close_notification()
        self.go_to_target_profile()
        sleep(3)
        self.click_on_following()
        self.move_mouse()
        self.scroll_down()
        self.driver.close()

    def move_mouse(self):
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        following_list = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']//div[@role = 'button']")
        actions.move_to_element(following_list).perform()
        sleep(3)

    def scroll_down(self):
        number_of_following = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/shriar.ha/following/']/span").get_attribute("innerHTML")
        print(number_of_following)
        number_of_following = int(number_of_following)
        if number_of_following > 7:
            number_of_scrolls = (number_of_following / 7)+3
            for i in range(int(number_of_scrolls)):
                self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                sleep(2)

    def click_on_following(self):
        following_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/shriar.ha/following/']")
        following_button.click()
        sleep(5)

    def close_notification(self):
        try: 
            sleep(3)
            close_noti_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Not Now')]")
            close_noti_btn.click()
            sleep(2)
        except:
            pass

    def go_to_target_profile(self):
        target_profile_url = self.main_url + "/" + self.target_username + "/"
        self.driver.get(target_profile_url)

    def log_in(self):
        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
        login_button.click()
        sleep(5)
        username_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        username_input.send_keys(self.username)
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)
        password_input.submit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

as you can see, it logins in instagram , then it goes to the target username which you give to the program and then it clicks on following , so it shows the following list . this is not completed yet , it should do other things but for now im stuck in this step .

my problem is that when i click on following . it opens a small window . and that's where you can see the following list , I want to scroll down this list. see the picture below :

[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffj8T.png)

i want to scroll down the following list but instead my code scrolls down the main page , i mean the page that's on the back. I realized that when i get my mouse cursor on the following list , i can scroll it with my mouse, so i decided to write a function to get my mouse cursor on the list and then scroll it , but it was not successful.

anyone got an idea what i i should do?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works fine with me:

```
def scroll_down(self):
    number_of_following = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/shriar.ha/following/']/span").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(number_of_following)
    number_of_following = int(number_of_following)
    if number_of_following > 7:
        number_of_scrolls = (number_of_following / 7)+3
        for i in range(int(number_of_scrolls)):
            #scroll by element
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@role='dialog']//button[text()='Follow'])["+number_of_following+"]"))
            time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was kinda helpful but it didn't solve my problem. this code runs on your machine? mine shows error , it cant locate the element.it's because the element is not loaded yet. for example i have 200 following , it cant find the 200th div to scroll to.

Comment: Thanks , I fixed it. I changed your answer a little and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bothering moving the mouse and clicking?
You should be able to crawl an account using a library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Alternatively, there are programs already doing that, that you can get inspired from.

Here are some:

- [Photo and video crawler](https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper)
- [This one](https://github.com/iammrhelo/InstagramCrawler) seems to also fetch followers

Unless you are specifically asked for it, I don't think this is a viable solution to move the cursor around and click each link.

Comment: because i want to get all the followers and have them on a list . I have to scroll down to button of the following list to load the html . when I open the following list , i only have access to a dozen off followers and others are not loaded in the page source yet. and i don't want to click on all of them , i want to active the following list so i can scroll this page instead of the main page